# Writing to a File Within an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, file, actionlistener, event-dispatch-thread

So, when I press a certain button, my file is supposed to "safely" update. The code I have for that is:

```
  public void writeBallot() throws IOException{
    //need to make a new file
    File realfile = new File("Ballots.txt");
    File tempfile = new File("ballottemp.txt");
    tempfile.createNewFile();
    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(tempfile);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i<theButtons.length; i ++)
        p.println(indivelection.get(i) + ":" + intcounts[i]);

    realfile.delete();

    tempfile.renameTo(realfile);
```

And when I press a certain button, among other things, this method is supposed to execute. The code i wrote for the button is:

```
if(e.getSource()==castVoteButton){

            int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you are done voting?", "Are You Sure?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                for (int j = 0; j<thePanels.length; j++){
                ((Ballot) thePanels[j]).buttonStatus(false);
                ((Ballot)thePanels[j]).checkyocolors();
                }
                castVoteButton.setEnabled(false);
                loginButton.setEnabled(true);

                for (int p = 0; p<thePanels.length; p++)
                    try {
                        ((Ballot)thePanels[p]).writeBallot();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();}
```

Now, I have tested my method to write update the file in another class and it seems to work, but once I wrap it in the try, catch, which is apparently required for the ActionListener, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions or hints so that I can implement my method when the JButton is pressed?

Comment: Does "Heyyyy" is output on your console?

Comment: Change `catch (IOException e1) {
                        System.out.println("Heyyyy");
                    }` to `catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }` which is both shorter and more informative. ;)

Comment: BTW 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Copy/paste input/output into the question & use code formatting for it.

Comment: Ohhh, I'm sorry, I forgot I put that in there, hahaa. No it doesn't, and I had catch (IOExcpetion e1) {e1.printStackTrace();} but that did nothing either.

Comment: File I/O can potentially take a long time (especially on my PC where I get the drives to spin down when not in use).  Calling such actions from the EDT will effectively block the EDT.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead implement a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: *"Ohhh, I'm sorry, I forgot I put that in there"*  Rather than apologies, how about an edit with an SSCCE of non-joke code (along with the I/O)?

Comment: Alright, I updated my code to what I had originally. I don't really know how to make this post any shorter....

Comment: `delete` and `renameTo` won't throw exceptions, you may want to check there return results (`boolean`) and throw an exception of your own if they return false

Comment: Have you flushed the PrintWriter after doing the file writing?

Comment: Dont forget to close any open streams i.e `PrinterWriter#close()`, or alternatively wrap your creation of `PrinterWriter` in a *try with resources* block which will close streams as java leaves the scop of the *try with resources*. Also I would recommend using an anonymous inner class `ActionListener` for every `JButton` with separate functionality.